# R error: "Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column `description` is unknown"

Tags: r

I am trying to run a script with Rstudio, and I am encountering the following issue:
When I run the script, this error message appears in the console:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
>     Column `description` is unknown

For reference, here is the code which I got from https://github.com/holnburger/Emoji-FB-analysis

I am completely new to R, and I cant explain why this error occurs. the function grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) is not even in the code, so I am guessing it comes from one of the installed packages?

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: There is no column `description` in the dataset .....

Comment: You mean in the provided csv?
e: In rstudio, it says under environment -> emDict -> description. I was guessing the script referred to that one?
e2: If I try to put "tag" in there, instead of description, it gives me the same error message. tag is available in the provided csv

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) in your question. This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @MalikMeyer-Heder It looks like the `EN` column in the provided csv gets renamed to `description` in line 84 of the `R` file here: https://github.com/holnburger/Emoji-FB-analysis/blob/master/emoji_analysis.R

Comment: @meenaparam when I remove that line it gives me an error code that the language setting for the file is not set, also description gets a new values a few lines below, where this is written: 
description <- emDict$description
e: I'm trying to make a reproducible example right now